# Tables and their content are shifting aside - why?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have several tables and their content looks fine in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5y7majq/), but on another website opened in the same browser everything - table, content - shifts to the right ([screenshot](https://images2.imgbox.com/72/41/7wkGPAtE_o.jpg)). How can I force the content to look like it does in JSFiddle example above? Everything should be moved back to the left (see the arrows on the screenshot). 
Thank you!

Here is the original code:

```html
<table style="height: 28px; width: 99.0328%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden;" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 13.0819%; height: 18px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 400; display: inline;">Some text</span></td>
      <td style="width: 63.7345%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 13.0819%;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 400; display: inline;">&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td style="width: 63.7345%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 13.0819%; height: 10px;"><img style="display: block; margin: 0px auto 30px auto;" src="https://content.linkedin.com/content/dam/me/business/en-us/amp/brand-site/v2/bg/LI-Bug.svg.original.svg" alt="" width="120" height="120" /></td>
      <td style="width: 63.7345%; height: 10px;">
        <table style="height: 46px; width: 32.4247%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden;" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 18px;">
              <td style="width: 100%; height: 10px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 18.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #454545; display: inline;">TITLE</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 18px;">
              <td style="width: 100%; height: 18px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 17px; font-weight: 600; color: #f25e30; display: inline;">Description</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table style="height: 74px; width: 38.1632%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden;" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 18px;">
              <td style="width: 10.1%; height: 18px;"><img src="https://y5t6h9a6.stackpathcdn.com/39f70a22-cae2-45dd-b2a1-ae008217d0c3/img.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></td>
              <td style="width: 690.907%; height: 18px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 400; color: #454545; display: inline;">phone number</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by **another website**? Do you copy and paste your code in local text-editor and see in your PC browser and that is different from your **jsfiddle** code?

Comment: Yes, kind of: this code is the email signature, so I plug it into the email service provider's website and what I see differs from what JSFiddle shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, you want to shift the contents to the left in any situation. But first you should know the **reason** of this behavior. The reason is **CSS relative units**. In CSS you can define the unit of your width, height or any other property in two ways:

1. With relative units like `%` or `vw` or ...
2. With absolute units like `px`.

The second one is suitable for cases when you want that an element (here the `table` tag) has a fixed value (for example a fixed `width`) regardless of the browser (here browser width). When you put your code in `jsfiddle`, it shows the result in bottom-right part of the browser. So the width for showing the content is limited and because you defined your width relative (`width: 99.0328%`) to the width of parent element (here the `body` tag), you see that the elements are dense and space between them are low. If you see that code in a PC browser (that has more width) you get a **different** result (like the picture you posted). So one solution for that is to put all the table in a `<section>` tag and give an absolute width to that `<section>` tag like the code below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<section style="width: 606px">
<table style="height: 28px; width: 99.0328%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden;" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
        <td style="width: 13.0819%; height: 18px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 400; display: inline;">Some text</span></td>
        <td style="width: 63.7345%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 13.0819%;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 400; display: inline;">&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td style="width: 63.7345%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
        <td style="width: 13.0819%; height: 10px;"><img style="display: block; margin: 0px auto 30px auto;" src="https://content.linkedin.com/content/dam/me/business/en-us/amp/brand-site/v2/bg/LI-Bug.svg.original.svg" alt="" width="120" height="120" /></td>
        <td style="width: 63.7345%; height: 10px;">
            <table style="height: 46px; width: 32.4247%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden;" border="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr style="height: 18px;">
                    <td style="width: 100%; height: 10px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 18.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #454545; display: inline;">TITLE</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 18px;">
                    <td style="width: 100%; height: 18px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 17px; font-weight: 600; color: #f25e30; display: inline;">Description</span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table style="height: 74px; width: 38.1632%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden;" border="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr style="height: 18px;">
                    <td style="width: 10.1%; height: 18px;"><img src="https://y5t6h9a6.stackpathcdn.com/39f70a22-cae2-45dd-b2a1-ae008217d0c3/img.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 690.907%; height: 18px;"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14.0px; font-style: normal; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 400; color: #454545; display: inline;">phone number</span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to learn more about `CSS units` I suggest to read more tutorials like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).